# React Native - how to use map function on an object

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating an APP that get some data from fetch function. No problem here. The array has the data correctly. I'm doing it like this:

```
 constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      fetching: false,
      api: []
    }
  }

componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ fetching: true })

    api.getMonuments().then(res => {
      this.setState({
        api: res,
        fetching: false
      })
    })
  }
```

[I got this data: an array of 4 objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qKJL.jpg)

Then I want to pass that data to another scene. I'm doing it like this:

```
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={[styles.button, {marginBottom:0}]}
        onPress={() => navigate('Monumento', this.state.api)}
        underlayColor='#000'
      >
        <View style={styles.buttonContent}>
          <Animatable.Text
            style={styles.buttonText}
            animation="bounceInLeft"
            duration={1500}
          >
          Click here!
          </Animatable.Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
```

On the other scene I get that data with the navigation.state.params but the problem now is that there is no more an array with 4 objects in it, but instead there is an object that have 4 objects in it...if I console log the data [that is what's appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx6M4.jpg)

```
render(){

    const api = this.props.navigation.state.params;

    console.log('API:', api)
    ...
```

Now I want to use the map function but I can't because 'api' is not a function...How can I workaround this?

Comment: I guess you are using react navigation. If so, then your call to navigate function should be like this: navigate('Monumento', {api: this.state.api}). And you can retrieve it like this: this.props.navigation.state.params.api. Navigate function takes screen name and params object. Read this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are accessing params object, but what you want is api array. I guess you are using react navigation. If so, then your call to navigate function should be like this:

```
navigate('Monumento', {api: this.state.api}).
```

And you can retrieve it like this:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.api.
```

Navigate function takes screen name and params object.

Read this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens

Answer (score 8):

```
render(){
   var api={"bar":"nihao"};
     return(
        <View>
        {Object.entries(api).map(([key,v])=>{
            return <View key={key}><Text>{v}</Text></View>
        })}
        </View>

      )
```

}
   api is a single object not array.

api is a array.

```
render(){
   var api=[{"bar":"nihao"},{"bar":"nihao2"},{"bar":"nihao3"}];
     return(
        <View>
        {api.map((v,index)=>{
             return <View key={index}><Text>{v.bar}</Text></View>
        })}
        </View>

      )
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Object.entries** with RN for mapping the key/value pairs of an object. Eg:

```
const api = { 'foo': 'bar', 'foz': 'baz'};
...
render() {
  return (
    Object.entries(api).map(([key, value]) => {
      return <View key={key}>{value}</View>
    });
  )
}
```